# Embedded subshift in $[0,1]$ has dimension $0$?

Tags: dynamical-systems, entropy, ergodic-theory, dimension-theory-analysis, hausdorff-measure

I was wondering whether most embeddings of one-dimensional subshifts have zero Hausdorff dimension? Given a finite alphabet $\mathcal{A}= \{ 0,...,d-1 \}$ and $\Omega\subseteq \mathcal{A}^\mathbb{N}$, we can encode  $\Omega$ to $[0,1]$ via $\omega \overset{\iota}{ \mapsto} \sum_{n=1}^\infty \omega_n \cdot d^{-n}$. I am interseted in the Haudorff dimension of $\iota(\Omega)$, when $\Omega$ is a closed and shift invariant subset.

A result by Furstenberg, which was later generalized by Stephen Simpson in [Symbolic dynamics: entropy = dimension = complexity](https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.04394), seems to imply that the Hausdorff dimension is the same as the entropy of a subshift and the Box counting dimension. Given the standard metric on $\mathcal{A}^\mathbb{N}$, it looks like one can generate plenty of $0$-dimensional sets arising naturally.
I was under the assumptions that it is hard to come up with natural non-trivial examples of $0$-dimensional sets.

I was wondering whether there is a fault in this reasoning? Or perhaps this should not be surprising at all?

Comment: Well, why did you write "... it looks like one can generate plenty" of examples? If you have plenty of examples at hand, that would seem to answer your question.

Comment: @LeeMosher It seems the question is if for a closed invariant subset that is generic w/r/t say Hausdorff distance the dimension/entropy is zero.

Comment: Perhaps, but, I would to know what the OP thinks the question is about.

Comment: @LeeMosher I was under the impression that it is hard to find "interesting" examples of $0$-dimensional sets. But I have read somewhere that subshifts generically have entropy $0$, and in fact most subshifts I am familiar with seem to have $0$ entropy. This question was more of a verification whether the way to generate sets with $0$ Harsdorff dimension is correct.